# Could I use a few locations for the same font with the same format in CSS?

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use the link to CDN, but if CDN is not available I want to load the font from the directory on my web server.

I try to find solution, but every example show different locations for different format (woff, truetype, etc.), but I want to use different links for the same font with the same format. Could I do it using CSS?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want. But I think you're thinking of `@font-face` which allows you to specify multiple links for certain fonts in many formats. More at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: @Code_Dummy00 I want to set few urls for the same format. I want reduce load on my server, but if CDN is not available I want that client load font from my server.